# Optimization SQL query an

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two views that to be optimised

```
--create view [dbo].[vw_trnSchemeActivityExecutionStatus]
--as
select 
    mstSchemeID, mstSchemeName, mstSchemeNFOStartDate, mstSchemeNFOClosureDate, 
    mstSchemeAllotmentDate, mstSchemeIsActive,mstSchemeNFOType, mstSchemeIsWoundOff, 
    mstSchemeCompletedActivity, mstschemeCreatedOn,
    Completed, Pending, PendingToday, PendingDueDate, FutureActivity,
    (PendingDueDate + PendingToday + FutureActivity + Completed) as Total 
from
    (select 
         sum(case when ActivityExecutionDueDate <> '' 
                       and convert(varchar(10), ActivityExecutionDueDate, 112) < convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 112) 
                       and (isnull(trnActivityExecutionDate, '') = '' or trnActivityExecutionStatus= 'P')
                     then 1 
                     else 0 
              end) as PendingDueDate,
         sum(case when ActivityExecutionDueDate <> '' 
                       and convert(varchar(10), ActivityExecutionDueDate, 112) > convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 112)  
                       and isnull(trnActivityExecutionDate, '') = '' 
                     then 1 
                     else 0 
              end) as FutureActivity,
         sum(case when ActivityExecutionDueDate <> '' 
                       and isnull(trnActivityExecutionDate, '') = '' 
                       and convert(varchar(10), ActivityExecutionDueDate, 112) = convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 112)
                     then 1 
                     else 0 
              end) as PendingToday,
         sum(case when ActivityExecutionDueDate <> '' 
                       and isnull(trnActivityExecutionDate, '') = '' 
                     then 1 
                     else 0 
              end) as Pending,
         sum(case when ActivityExecutionDueDate <> '' 
                       and trnActivityExecutionDate <> '' 
                       and trnActivityExecutionStatus = 'C'  
                     then 1 
                     else 0 
              end) as Completed,
         mstSchemeID, mstSchemeName, mstSchemeNFOStartDate, mstSchemeNFOClosureDate,
         mstSchemeAllotmentDate, mstSchemeIsActive, mstSchemeNFOType,    
         mstSchemeIsWoundOff, mstSchemeCompletedActivity, mstschemeCreatedOn
     from
         vw_trnSchemeActivityExecution 
      where
          ActivityCheckListItemIsActive = 1 and mstSchemeIsActive = 1
      group by 
          mstSchemeID, mstSchemeName, mstSchemeNFOStartDate, mstSchemeNFOClosureDate,
          mstSchemeAllotmentDate, mstSchemeIsActive, mstSchemeNFOType, mstSchemeIsWoundOff,
          mstSchemeCompletedActivity, mstschemeCreatedOn) b
```

In this output comes as 54 rows in 1:40 minutes.

And the second view which is used in the above view is:

```
--CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_trnSchemeActivityExecution]
--AS
select mstSchemeID,mstSchemeName,mstSchemeNFOStartDate,mstSchemeNFOClosureDate,mstSchemeAllotmentDate,
mstSchemeIsActive, mstSchemeIsWoundOff, mstSchemeCompletedActivity, mstSchemeNFOType,mstSchemeCreatedOn,
ActivityExecutionID,ActivityExecutionName, ActivityCheckListItemIsActive,ActivityCheckListItemDocumentTemplateID
,ActivityCheckListItemDocumentAttachmentRequired,ActivityCheckListItemEmailGroupID, ActivityCheckListItemEmailTemplateID,
ActivityCheckListItemNatureofActivity ,ActivityExecutionDueDate,ActivityCheckListItemAllowExternalDocument,
t.trnActivityExecutionID,t.trnActivityExecutionSchemeID,t.trnActivityExecutionDate,
t.trnActivityExecutionStatus,t.trnActivityExecutionCreatedBy,
t.trnActivityExecutionDueDate, t.trnSchemeActivityExecutionID, t.trnActivityExecutionRemark,
CASE WHEN cnt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'IsDocumentAttached'
    from
    (select  
    s.mstSchemeID, s.mstSchemeName, 
    s.mstSchemeNFOStartDate,
    s. mstSchemeNFOClosureDate,
    s.mstSchemeAllotmentDate, 
    s.mstSchemeIsActive,
    s.mstSchemeIsWoundOff,
    s.mstSchemeCompletedActivity,
    s.mstSchemeNFOType,
    s.mstSchemeCreatedOn,
    a.ActivityCheckListItemID as [ActivityExecutionID],
    a.ActivityCheckListItemName as [ActivityExecutionName],
    a.ActivityCheckListItemIsActive,
    a.ActivityCheckListItemDocumentTemplateID,
    a.ActivityCheckListItemDocumentAttachmentRequired,
    a.ActivityCheckListItemEmailGroupID,
    a.ActivityCheckListItemEmailTemplateID,
    a.ActivityCheckListItemNatureofActivity, 
    a.ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOn,
    a.ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOperator,
    a.ActivityCheckListItemTimelineDays,
    a.ActivityCheckListItemAllowExternalDocument,
    case 
        when ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOn = 'S' and ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOperator = '1'   
        then (select dbo.fnGetNextPreviousWorkingDay(s.mstSchemeNFOStartDate,a.ActivityCheckListItemTimelineDays))

    when ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOn = 'S' and ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOperator = '0'   
    then (select dbo.fnGetNextPreviousWorkingDay(s.mstSchemeNFOStartDate,-a.ActivityCheckListItemTimelineDays))

    when ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOn = 'C' and ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOperator = '1'   
    then (select dbo.fnGetNextPreviousWorkingDay(s.mstSchemeNFOClosureDate,a.ActivityCheckListItemTimelineDays))

    when ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOn = 'C' and ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOperator = '0'   
    then (select dbo.fnGetNextPreviousWorkingDay(s.mstSchemeNFOClosureDate,-a.ActivityCheckListItemTimelineDays))

    when ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOn = 'A' and ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOperator = '1'   
    then (select dbo.fnGetNextPreviousWorkingDay(s.mstSchemeAllotmentDate,a.ActivityCheckListItemTimelineDays))

    when ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOn = 'A' and ActivityCheckListItemTimelineOperator = '0'   
    then (select dbo.fnGetNextPreviousWorkingDay(s.mstSchemeAllotmentDate,-a.ActivityCheckListItemTimelineDays))

end as [ActivityExecutionDueDate]
from vw_mstScheme s cross join
mstActivityCheckListItems a where a.ActivityCheckListItemIsActive = 1 and s.mstSchemeNFOType='C') m    --s.mstSchemeIsActive = 1 and 
left join trnSchemeActivityExecution t on t.trnActivityExecutionSchemeID = m.mstSchemeID and 
          t.trnActivityExecutionID = m.ActivityExecutionID 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT mstActivityID,count(TemplateID) as cnt FROM dbo.mstActivityItemDocuments a
inner join mstTemplates t on t.TemplateID = a.mstDocumentID  and (t.TemplateType = 'D' or t.TemplateType = 'B')
GROUP BY mstActivityID
)cte1 ON m.ActivityExecutionID= cte1.mstActivityID
```

In this view 9500 rows comes in 02:35 Minutes

Can anyone help to optimize this query

Comment: There is no chances to anyone could help you until you provide more details. You should start go on the somewhat lower level and at first try to figure out what happens on the `vw_mstScheme` level? Then you may try to optimize views on next levels.

Anyway, you would need to provide info about structures you are using here (tables, indexes and so on).

Comment: Use Execution plan and missing indexes hint in SSMS. Like this the question is too broad and unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Execution Plan is best way to start with the  Query Optimization. this will shows the bottleneck, which part of the query is longer duration for execution.

also, share the rows count available in the source views. To understand no. of rows the query process to produce these results.